# Is there a term for this property of magmas?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, magma

There exists an element of the magma c such that for all x: $ x*x=c $

The consequence of this is that the elements on the diagonal of the Cayley table are all the same, e.a:

$ * = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

For all x in this magma: $ x*x=1 $

$c$ does not have to be $x$ (making it idempotent), or the identity element of the magma.

Comment: *Unipotent*, if $1$ is the identity element of such magma?

Comment: c (1 for the example) doesn't have to be the identity element.

Comment: Yeah, you mean something more general, I see. I'll search again and post if I find any interesting reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a few months of mumbling, since I first read this question, and I'm ready to give you an answer. First things first.

A magma $(G,\ast)$ is said to be *idempotent* if $x\ast x=x$ for all $x\in G$. This is the case of elements of $G$ pairwise distinct on the diagonal of the Cayley table:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c & \ldots\\ \hline
a & a &  &  &  \\
b &  & b &  &  \\
c &  &  & c & \\
\vdots &  &  &  & \ddots\\
\end{array}$$

Instead, in literature we find *two* definitions for unipotence of a magma:
[$$x\ast x=e\qquad \forall x\in G,\tag{1}$$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unipotent_magma)
where $e$ is the identity element of $G$ (so, we are assuming already that $G$ has identity element), and:
[$$x\ast x=y\ast y\qquad \forall x,y\in G.\tag{2}$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29#Classification_by_properties)
The condition in line 1 of your question ($x\ast x=c$ for all $x$, for some generic $c$) is equivalent to definition (2). You already provided an example of magma without identity where the less restrictive definition (2) holds. We can assume this latter as the definition of *unipotence* for an arbitrary magma while in a magma with identity $e$, hence in all monoids, definition (2) implies definition (1) since it must be $e\ast e=e$.

If (1) holds, but also if only (2) holds, then *the elements on the diagonal of the Cayley table are all the same*, as you mentioned.